# Mostrar mensaje con Flash en Laravel 5 al redireccionar

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de mostrar un mensaje (Notificación) al crear un usuario usando Flash (Laracast).

En mi controller de usuario tengo la función de store:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $user = new User($request->all());
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();

    Flash::success("Se ha registrado el usuario ".$user->name." de manera exitosa!");

    return redirect()->route('admin.users.index');    
}
```

luego he agregado: `@include('flash::message')` en el body de mi plantilla.

Al crear un usuario y ejecutar la redirección el mensaje no aparece en la página `/users` (que corresponde al index)

Si utilizo, `return $this->index();` me funciona perfecto pero la *URL* no cambia a `/users` como esperaba.

He probado poniendo un mensaje directo en el *controller index* y funciona bien. (Es decir **no** usando redirección) Ej:

```
public function index(){
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

    Flash::success("Mensaje de prueba");

    return view('admin.users.users')->with('users', $users);
}
```

Cualquier ayuda me vendría bien.

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que en Laravel 5, los mensajes de flash son puestos a la sesión que hace la request, algo tipo:

```
//En tu controller
Session::flash('flash_message', 'Mensaje de prueba');
//aquí haces render o redirect a tu view
```

Y en tu vista:

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
{{Session::get('flash_message')}}
@endif
```

De esa manera puedes desplegar tus mensajes de flash.

Te recomiendo visitar laracasts, es una referencia genial para los que estamos interesados en el framework. El vídeo concreto para esto lo puedes ver en el [aquí](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/20).

Saludos.

Comment: Tampoco me funcionaba de esta manera, el error que tenia es que estoy usando la versión de Laravel 5.2.x , pero ya he encontrado mi problema. En la configuración de Kernel.php los middleware están alojados en $middlewareGroups y se deben de invocar de otra manera. Para usarlos de esta manera que he puesto mas arriba solo traslade todo a $middleware  . Ahí funciono correctamente.

Comment: Excelente, sería bueno que actualizaras tu pregunta describiendo cómo lo has resuelto, a alguien más le puede servir :)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Omar. Un abrazo !