# ¿Porque no se ejecutan los mensajes de Laracast/Flash en laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Instale Laracast/Flash en mi proyecto desarrollado en Laravel 5.2, todo esta perfecto, inserta y elimina y todo eso, pero cuando quiero mostrar un mensaje, no hace nada, es decir, realiza la opción pero no muestra el mensaje.

La vista tiene el Include de Flash `@include('flash::message')` pero aun asi no muestra nada.

¿Cual podria ser el problema?

Buscando e investigando el único que al parecer tiene la respuesta esta en este Link [Mostrar mensaje con Flash en Laravel 5 al redireccionar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2407/mostrar-mensaje-con-flash-en-laravel-5-al-redireccionar) [Jose Gratereaux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1612/jose-gratereaux), pero no explica cómo lo realizó.

Gracias de antemano pro la ayuda.

Comment: pusiste esto en el controlador? use Laracasts\Flash\Flash;

Answer (score 2):

1) Asegúrate de que hayas insertado bien el código en los providers

```
'providers' => [
Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableServiceProvider::class,
],
```

2) En tu controlador deberías escribir esto

```
Flash::success("Ejemplo..."); 
return view('admin.users.index');
```